# Uncaught in promise while waiting for json response

Tags: javascript, json, promise

I'm implementing Promises for the first time in JS and am getting uncaught in promise exception in console log while running the below code.

```
function data_present() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(api)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(message => { 
                console.log(message)
                if(message && Object.keys(message).length != 0) {
                    resolve()
                }
                else {
                    reject()
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

I am handling the result of the promise return value in the main function as below and am yet getting the uncaught in promise message:

```
function main() {
    data_present().then(() => {
        load_graph()
    }).catch(() => {
        data_present()
    })
}
```

The logic behind the data_present() is to wait till we get a non-empty JSON response at the API endpoint and keep polling it if JSON response is empty.

The exception I'm getting is as follows:

```
Uncaught (in promise) undefined
(anonymous) @ index.js:34
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:29
data_present @ index.js:26
(anonymous) @ index.js:56
Promise.catch (async)
getParametersData @ index.js:55
onclick @ (index):92
```

Comment: Please add the exact exception/error you are getting.

Comment: Wrapping `fetch()` in  `new Promise` is an anti-pattern since `fetch()` returns a promise itself

Comment: @Ivar I have added the error I see in console log in the question

Comment: @charlietfl so I can remove new Promise part  and say return fetch(api) ?

Comment: Why do you need to reject the promise?

Comment: @evolutionxbox So that I can poll the endpoint again and only resolve when there is data available from the endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might think about having one function to get, parse, and return the JSON from the API (no need to wrap your `fetch` in a promise as it already returns one), and use your polling function to check the returned data. If it's correct call one function, otherwise poll `getData` again. If there's an API error log that instead.

I've used `async/await` here but the principles are the same.

```js
// Simulates an API
// If the random number is a modulo of 5 set data
// to an object with a key/value pair, otherwise
// it set it to an empty object. If the random number
// is a modulo of 9 send an error, otherwise send the data.
function mockFetch() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    const data = rnd % 5 === 0 ? { name: 'Bob' } : {};
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (rnd % 9 === 0) rej('Connection error');
      res(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// `getData` simply gets a response from the API and parses it.
// I had to use JSON.parse here rather that await response.json()
// because I'm not using the actual fetch API.
async function getData() {
  const response = await mockFetch();
  return JSON.parse(response);
}

// The `poll` function does all the heavy-lifting
// first we initialise `count`
async function poll(count = 1) {

  console.log(`Polling ${count}`);

  // Try and get some data. If it's not an empty object
  // log the name (or in your case call loadGraph),
  // otherwise poll the API again after two seconds.
  // We wrap everything in a `try/catch`.
  try {

    const data = await getData();

    if (data && data.name) {
      console.log(data.name); // loadGraph
    } else {
      setTimeout(poll, 2000, ++count);
    }

  // If the API sends an error log that instead
  // and poll again after five seconds
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`${err}. Polling again in 5 seconds.`);
    setTimeout(poll, 5000, 1);
  }

}

poll();
```

And here's the version [based on Dai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70502940/1377002):

```js
function mockFetch() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    const data = rnd % 5 === 0 ? { name: 'Bob' } : {};
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (rnd % 9 === 0) rej('Connection error');
      res(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function getData() {
  const response = await mockFetch();
  return JSON.parse(response);
}

async function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time));
}

async function poll(count = 1) {

  do {

    console.log(`Polling ${count}`);

    try {
      const data = await getData();
      if (data && data.name) return data;
      await delay(2000);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`${err}. Polling again in 5 seconds.`);
      await delay(5000);
    }

    ++count;

  } while (count < 10);

  console.log(`Reached poll limit - ${count}.`);
  return false;

}

async function main() {
  console.log('First');
  console.log(await poll());
  console.log('Second');
}

main();
```

Comment: thank you. I was able to modify the code according to the template you provided. Also, can you please suggest some resources to improve my understanding of JS concepts

Comment: [MDN is all you need](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Answer (score -4):

Also `fetch` already returns a promise. So you shouldnt wrap it again (I included this in my example). The error comes from the second call to the function as described in the second catch block below

```js
function data_present() {
  return fetch(api)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(message => {
      console.log(message)
      if (!message || Object.keys(message).length === 0) {
        throw new Error('something went wrong');
      } 
    })
}

function main() {
  data_present()
    .then(() => {
      load_graph()
    }).catch(() => {
      return data_present() // the promise which is returned here was not caught in your example
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // another error
    })
}
```

Comment: What good is the empty return? This won't teach OP anything productive

Comment: resolve didn't have any value so the return just terminates the function here. Some value should be added if needed however the question didn't give me that info